# Counting entries in a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, django

I'm using django to list the number of cars sold in a particular dealership. (assuming there are only red and blue cars)
I have designed the query  in such a way that we could visualise cars at a monthly or weekly or yearly level. so the data in the table in going to be changing , so I have written the following javascript code to read the table that will be generated everytime . I have also used pagination to include only 10 in a page.
The code just reads what is available on the first page and returns 10 every single time whereas I need it to consider all the pages . Can someone help

```
<script>
  function counter(){
    
    
    var j = 6; //j=6 is the column id for colour in my table , so I'm, directly using it
    var total = 0;
    var red= 0;
    var blue= 0;
    
    var table = document.getElementById("datatable");
    
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) 
    {
      
      var Row = document.getElementById("datatable").rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
      
      var colour = document.getElementById("datatable").rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
      
      //alert(document.getElementById("datatable").rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
      if (colour == "red")
      {
        red= red+ 1;
      }
      else if (colour== "blue")
      {
        blue= blue+ 1;
      
      }
      
    total = red+ blue;
    }
    
    document.getElementById("total_count").innerText = total;
    document.getElementById("red_count").innerText = red;
    document.getElementById("blue_count").innerText = blue;

    
  }
</script>
```

HTML to the table

```
<div class="menu">
      <table cellpadding="0" id="datatable" style="margin-top: 20px" style="margin-bottom:20px" class="table" >
      <thead>
        <tr class="text-light bg-dark">
          <th class="text-center" >Date</th>
          <th class="text-center" >Model</th>
          <th class="text-center" >CustomerName</th>
          <th class="text-center" >Mobile</th>
          <th class="text-center" >Adress</th>
          <th class="text-center" >Delivery</th>
          <th class="text-center" >Colour</th>
          
          
         
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>


        {% for obj in filter.qs %}
           <tr>
            
            <td class="text-center" >{{ obj.Date}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" >{{ obj.Model}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" >{{ obj.CustomerName}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" >{{ obj.Mobile}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" >{{ obj.Address}}</td>
            <td class="text-center" >{{ obj.Delivery }}</td>
            <td class="text-center" >{{ obj.Qa_Decision }}</td>
```

Comment: where does the colour variable come from? where do you use blood_group and or Row variables?

Comment: Please put more code, such as the HTML for the table.

Answer (score 1):

since there table with id 'datatable' exist, im assuming you using DataTables library

if you not using server side datatables pagination, you can access all data with rows().data() refrence https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().data()

if your using server side datatables or even not using datatables
you only can count that data in backend(django), since js cant access all that data